# Best variable types to use for floating-point value

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, printf

I have a `FLOAT` column in a SQL Server database that appears as follows in SQL Server Management Studio.

> 18.001

When I read that value into a `float` variable, and format it using `sprintf()` ("%f"), it appears as:

> 18.000999

When I read that value into a `double` variable, and format it using `sprintf()`, it appears as:

> 18.001000

Could I get some suggestions on this? The values being stored are generally under 100, with up to 3 decimal places. What is the best SQL Server type? What is the best C++ type? And should I be using some rounding technique to get it in the format I want?

*Note: I'm not actually using `sprintf()`, I'm using `CString.Format()`, but the expected behavior is the same.*

Comment: If you're concerned about precision, C++ got float < double < long double.

Comment: @nada: Right, but that seems a bit of overkill for a value that is less than 100.

Comment: @JonathanWood if you care about precision, it is not.

Comment: @SergeyA: Why would I need a `long double` for 3 decimal places? Seems really more of a formatting issue.

Comment: @JonathanWood the number is not representable exactly in floating point. The more precision you have, the closer you get to your *actual* number.

Comment: @SergeyA: I get that. But I can round to 3 decimal places without any more precision. For that reason, more precision seems like overkill here.

Comment: I am not understanding your problem. If you simply want to always round up to 3 decimal places, than just round up?

Comment: There is no best c++ datatype.  These inaccuracies are to be expected as explained in the referenced duplicate.

Comment: Yes I did, and many others like it.   The point of the flagged duplicate, if you read the answers, is that float datatypes are not precise and you should expect inconsistencies from language to language.

Comment: If it is stated somewhere in your question that you already understand about float precision, I am still missing it on re-read.  To me it reads as though you are mystified by the inconsistencies.  If you edit your question to be more focused on how best to work around these known inconsistencies, I'll vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

> The values being stored are generally under 100, with up to 3 decimal places.

SQL databases support the `numeric`/`decimal` (the two are synonyms) types for fixed-point values.  For your specific type, you could use `decimal(6, 3)`.  That is six significant digits, with three of them to the right of the decimal point.  These two values are called *scale* and *precision* respectively.

If the values can differ a bit from this, you might want a wider range.

With `decimal`/`numeric`, what-you-see-is-what-you-get.  I would recommend storing them in the database as fixed-point numbers.

Comment: Do you know the best C variable to hold such a value?

Comment: The biggest question would be on the proper C++ data type for it.

Comment: @SergeyA I would probably scale the value up to be an integer in my select statement or create a view. That way you could store the value in a normal C++ int and enjoy all the performance and convenience benefits of a usual primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question on it's face value, assuming floating point should be used and fixed point is not applicable.

Unless you are really tight on memory, there is really no reason to use anything for floating numbers in C++ but `double`. Float looses precision without giving you much in return. You can also try `long double`, but in my experience it is rather overkill. Also, if your compiler is MSVC, I have heard it's `long double`s are the same as `doubles`.

Answer (score -1):

In alternative to the fixed comma decimals [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961430/1312382) already, just use ordinary integers!

Instead of storing 18.001 *seconds*, you'd store 18001 *milliseconds*, you wouldn't store Euro, Pound, Dollar, but tenth of a cent or penny, ...

Type in C++ would be an integer as well, large enough to hold maximum numbers you need, e. g. `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, ...

Comment: I'm doing that for my currency values. However, I have some generic floating point column classes. I don't really want to tie down the number of decimal places to a fixed number.

Comment: Assuming IEEE754, floating point is not really suitable to represent currency values. Be aware that even a most simple value like 0.2 is periodic in binary, so cannot be represented exactly, no matter if you consider float or double. Fixed-comma arithmetics with integers are always precise, with exception, though, if e. g. needing to calculate interests. You will need some rounding then (e. g. `value = (value * 107 + 50) / 100`), but you can always have that at only those very specific points where you really need it (and can easily select rounding strategy as desired/required).

Comment: If you still insist on floating point, then I'd opt for the highest precision available, i. e. double or possibly even long double.